# CSS/JS not loading due to wrong path

Tags: magento2

I just installed a fresh Magento 2. 
Now when I fire it up, the CSS and JS is not loading.

I looked at the source and it always has the version of the deployment in the path, like `/pub/static/version1484648587/frontend/...` . This does not exist though, I only have `/pub/static/frontend.`

What am I making wrong?

Comment: have you manually delete pub/static folder?

Comment: No, I left everything like it was. Should I delete it manually and redeploy?

Comment: Have you check inside pub/static folder, .htaaccess file is there?

Comment: Yes, it is there

Comment: just deploy command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I did, it always has that version12345678 in the path and so the CSS/JS files can not be found

Comment: Remove all static folder conent manually, get just copy of .htaacess file from fresh magento 2.1.3 and keep inside pub/static folder and run deploy command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51942/discussion-between-arnie-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands for Magento 2.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did, that does not help unfortunately

Comment: run this chmod -R 777 pub/, chmod -R 777 var/

Comment: Does not help either ... why is this so hard? Isnt that just a basic installation? I did not even install any extension :|

Comment: sometime permission issue arries, so we need to run this command.

Comment: Friends don't let friends 777.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're missing or have the wrong `.htaccess` file in your pub/static folder

Just grab the latest/right one here -> github magento [pub/static](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess)

Mine was missing because of git ignoring the pub/static folder ...

Answer (score 0):

> /pub/static/version1484648587/frontend/... . This does not exist though

The `version*` directory does not exist because this is how Magento accomplishes versioning it's static assets so that when the site is updated (by a new deployment of the application, etc) with changes the browser will freshly download these assets rather than using a cached copy. Ensuring that changes are reflected on the site.

> I only have /pub/static/frontend.

This is normal. Your site's frontend static assets will reside in here under the following naming convention:

```
/pub/static/frontend/{themeVendorName}/{themeName}/{localeName}/*
```

If you do not have these files, there are two ways to go about getting them published there.

### 1 - If you are developing (example, in your localhost)

Make sure that Magento is running in developer mode by running the following CLI command:

```
./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

You can verify the current mode with the following command:

```
./bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

While running in developer mode, Magento will create symbolic links to your static resources on the fly (as in, during your HTTP requests) if the resource is not already there. This way, your changes to things such as `*.js` files and `*.html` files are reflected right away. *(for JS files, exception to this is your theme's `requirejs-config.js`)*. Changes to CSS files within your theme will be reflected right away as well if you are not using LESS / SASS for your styling efforts.

In the event that a symbolic link already exists, then you choose to override it in your local theme for the first time, you will have to eliminate the symbolic link for the new one to be generated.

For compiled CSS (CSS originating from LESS or SASS files depending on your implementation -- Magento ships with LESS out of the box) you can either utilize Grunt to recompile changes for you. (See Dev Docs: [Using Grunt for Magento Tasks](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html)). Or another simple approach to get your styles reprocessed is to simply delete the files.

### 2 - If you are not running developer mode (`default|production`)

If you are not running in developer mode, and need your assets published to `pub/static`, simply run the following command:

```
./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Without any additional parameters, this will deploy all themes.

### I see my theme files but my site still looks broken & unstyled :(

If this is the case, then the redirects meant to handle the versioning of files are not working correctly. The solution here, will depend on your setup.

**If you are running Apache**

Under apache, the redirects necessary will come shipped with Magento out of box within the `pub/static/.htaccess` file. We can see these here:

```
RewriteEngine On

## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
#RewriteBase /magento/pub/static/

# Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
```

For them to work via .htaccess, two main things are necessary on your apache configuration: `mod_rewrite` needs to be enabled, and `.htaccess` files need to be allowed to be parsed by httpd *(See [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride))*

Some people prefer `AllowOverride none`. In this scenario you will have to migrate Magento's `.htaccess` rules to your httpd configuration.

**If you are running nginx**

Nginx does not parse `.htaccess` files. You'll have to convert Magento's .htaccess rules to nginx syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Quick hack:
i have facing the same issue after run upgrade commend and spend hours to identify the issue.
during debugging i just checked css and js url and found both script url contain same folder name (version1530781167) which not exist in my magento setup.

i just created same name newfolder (version1530781167) under pub/static  and move frontend and adminhtml folder into version1530781167.
next i just click the refresh button and everything looks fine css and js both script loaded.

I hope this will help to save other guys time and effort. :)) cheers..